# C# Finding if a list contains an item duplicated 5 times

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates

I have a large List of strings. I want to know if the list contains any string duplicated exactly 5 times.

If the item is duplicated 6 times or more I don't want to know.

I assume their must be a better way than going through the list one by and counting how many instances of each string there are?

Is their an easy LINQ way to do it ?

Comment: "Is their an easy LINQ way to do it?" Of course there is, but it is not any "better" than going through the list one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing would be better performancewise, since you obviously need to iterate over the entire list at least once to do the counting. However in LINQ you can get by with less code, that is true. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var listOfFiveTimers = list.GroupBy(s => s)
                           .Where(g => g.Count() == 5)
                           .Select(g => g.Key)
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
stringListName.GroupBy(x => x).Any(x => x.Count() == 5);
```

tested using

```
 var stringListName = new string[] { "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b" };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 bool duplicated5times = list.GroupBy(x=>x).Any(x=>x.Count() == 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
    l.Add("a");
    l.Add("a");
    l.Add("a");
    l.Add("b");
    l.Add("b");
    l.Add("b");
    l.Add("b");
    l.Add("b");
    l.Add("c");
    l.Add("c");
    l.Add("c");
    l.Add("c");
    l.Add("c");
    l.Add("c");

    l.GroupBy
    (
        x => x
    )
    .Select 
    (
        x => 
        new
        {
            x.Key,
            count = x.Count ()
        }
     )
     .Where 
     (
        x => x.count==5
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not beautiful, but this will do it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2};

    var over = items.Distinct().ToList().Where(i=>items.Where(it => it == i).Count() > 5);
    Console.Read();
}
```